# What is difference between the malaria (cross) types?

Tags: pathology

When the doctor does the diagnose she says "you have malaria. 2 crosses". Now, I've heard those crosses go from 1 to 5, and historically I've had from 1 to 4, but I wonder: what is the difference between them?

Also there's this popular thing of people saying that an odd number is more dangerous than an even number. Is this scientific or something?

Cheers